# Recreating a Bubble Chart with a Play Axis using Vega

Tags: powerbi, visualization, vega

I have created a bubble chart in Power BI using Vega, plotting multiple values on the same chart. I would like to recreate the play axis feature to dynamically update the chart using a time variable 'periodIndex'.

I have created a slider based on this time variable, however I would like the chart to play through the time period once a Play tick box is selected. How do I connect the tick box to a signal which increments periodIndex every second?

An example of my code is below. When I tick play there is no response.

```
{
  "width": 1000,
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "hover",
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "*:pointerover",
          "encode": "hover"
        },
        {
          "events": "*:pointerout",
          "encode": "leave"
        },
        {
          "events": "*:pointerdown",
          "encode": "select"
        },
        {
          "events": "*:pointerup",
          "encode": "release"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "xoffset",
      "update": "-(height + padding.bottom)"
    },
    {
      "name": "yoffset",
      "update": "-(width + padding.left)"
    },
    {
      "name": "xrange",
      "update": "[0, width]"
    },
    {
      "name": "yrange",
      "update": "[height, 0]"
    },
    {
      "name": "down",
      "value": null,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "touchend",
          "update": "null"
        },
        {
          "events": "pointerdown, touchstart",
          "update": "xy()"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "xcur",
      "value": null,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "pointerdown, touchstart, touchend",
          "update": "slice(xdom)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "ycur",
      "value": null,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "pointerdown, touchstart, touchend",
          "update": "slice(ydom)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "delta",
      "value": [0, 0],
      "on": [
        {
          "events": [
            {
              "source": "window",
              "type": "pointermove",
              "consume": true,
              "between": [
                {"type": "pointerdown"},
                {
                  "source": "window",
                  "type": "pointerup"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "touchmove",
              "consume": true,
              "filter": "event.touches.length === 1"
            }
          ],
          "update": "down ? [down[0]-x(), y()-down[1]] : [0,0]"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "anchor",
      "value": [0, 0],
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "wheel",
          "update": "[invert('xscale', x()), invert('yscale', y())]"
        },
        {
          "events": {
            "type": "touchstart",
            "filter": "event.touches.length===2"
          },
          "update": "[(xdom[0] + xdom[1]) / 2, (ydom[0] + ydom[1]) / 2]"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "zoom",
      "value": 1,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "wheel!",
          "force": true,
          "update": "pow(1.001, event.deltaY * pow(16, event.deltaMode))"
        },
        {
          "events": {"signal": "dist2"},
          "force": true,
          "update": "dist1 / dist2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "dist1",
      "value": 0,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {
            "type": "touchstart",
            "filter": "event.touches.length===2"
          },
          "update": "pinchDistance(event)"
        },
        {
          "events": {"signal": "dist2"},
          "update": "dist2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "dist2",
      "value": 0,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {
            "type": "touchmove",
            "consume": true,
            "filter": "event.touches.length===2"
          },
          "update": "pinchDistance(event)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "xdom",
      "update": "slice(xext)",
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {"signal": "delta"},
          "update": "[xcur[0] + span(xcur) * delta[0] / width, xcur[1] + span(xcur) * delta[0] / width]"
        },
        {
          "events": {"signal": "zoom"},
          "update": "[anchor[0] + (xdom[0] - anchor[0]) * zoom, anchor[0] + (xdom[1] - anchor[0]) * zoom]"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "ydom",
      "update": "slice(yext)",
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {"signal": "delta"},
          "update": "[ycur[0] + span(ycur) * delta[1] / height, ycur[1] + span(ycur) * delta[1] / height]"
        },
        {
          "events": {"signal": "zoom"},
          "update": "[anchor[1] + (ydom[0] - anchor[1]) * zoom, anchor[1] + (ydom[1] - anchor[1]) * zoom]"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "size",
      "update": "clamp(20 / span(xdom), 1, 1000)"
    },
    {
      "name": "play",
      "value": false,
      "bind": {"input": "checkbox"}
    },
    {
      "name": "periodIndex",
      "value": 202205,
      "bind": {
        "input": "range",
        "min": 202205,
        "max": 202305,
        "step": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "dataset",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "extent",
          "field": "Bubble Granularity Internal Risk Capital",
          "signal": "xext"
        },
        {
          "type": "extent",
          "field": "Bubble Granularity EVA",
          "signal": "yext"
        },
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum['Period_id'] == periodIndex"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "update": {
    "trails": {"value": 1000},
    "update": {"signal": "periodIndex"},
    "hover": {"opacity": {"value": 1}},
    "select": {
      "opacity": {"value": 0.5}
    }
  },
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "domain": {
        "data": "dataset",
        "fields": [
          "Bubble Granularity Internal Risk Capital",
          "Sector Average Risk Capital"
        ],
        "signal": "xdom"
      },
      "range": {"signal": "xrange"},
      "nice": true
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "domain": {
        "data": "dataset",
        "fields": [
          "Bubble Granularity EVA",
          "Sector average EVA"
        ],
        "signal": "ydom"
      },
      "range": {"signal": "yrange"},
      "nice": true
    },
    {
      "name": "size",
      "type": "linear",
      "round": true,
      "nice": false,
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {
        "data": "dataset",
        "field": "Spot Exposure"
      },
      "range": [4, 3000]
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {
        "data": "dataset",
        "field": "ou2_full_name",
        "sort": true
      },
      "range": {
        "scheme": "pbiColorNominal"
      }
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "scale": "xscale",
      "orient": "top",
      "title": "Internal Risk Capital",
      "offset": {"signal": "xoffset"}
    },
    {
      "scale": "yscale",
      "orient": "right",
      "title": "R12 EVA",
      "offset": {"signal": "yoffset"}
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "marks",
      "type": "symbol",
      "sort": {
        "field": ["datum['Period_id']"],
        "order": ["ascending"]
      },
      "style": ["point"],
      "from": {"data": "dataset"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "tooltip": {
            "signal": "datum"
          },
          "stroke": {
            "scale": "color",
            "field": "ou2_full_name"
          },
          "x": [
            {
              "scale": "xscale",
              "field": "Bubble Granularity Internal Risk Capital"
            }
          ],
          "y": [
            {
              "scale": "yscale",
              "field": "Bubble Granularity EVA"
            }
          ],
          "size": {
            "scale": "size",
            "field": "Spot Exposure"
          }
        }
      },
      "update": {
        "x": {
          "scale": "xscale",
          "field": "Bubble Granularity Internal Risk Capital"
        },
        "y": {
          "scale": "yscale",
          "field": "Bubble Granularity EVA"
        },
        "size": {"signal": "size"}
      },
      "hover": {
        "fill": {"value": "firebrick"}
      },
      "leave": {
        "fill": {"value": "steelblue"}
      },
      "select": {
        "size": {
          "signal": "size",
          "mult": 5
        }
      },
      "release": {
        "size": {"signal": "size"}
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "marks2",
      "type": "symbol",
      "style": ["square"],
      "sort": {
        "field": ["datum['Period_id']"],
        "order": ["ascending"]
      },
      "from": {"data": "dataset"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "tooltip": {
            "signal": "datum"
          },
          "fill": {"value": "orange"},
          "x": [
            {
              "scale": "xscale",
              "field": "Comparison Granularity Risk Capital"
            }
          ],
          "y": [
            {
              "scale": "yscale",
              "field": "Comparison Granularity EVA"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "update": {
        "x": {
          "scale": "xscale",
          "field": "Comparison Granularity Risk Capital"
        },
        "y": {
          "scale": "yscale",
          "field": "Comparison Granularity EVA"
        },
        "size": {"signal": "size"}
      },
      "hover": {
        "fill": {"value": "firebrick"}
      },
      "leave": {
        "fill": {"value": "steelblue"}
      },
      "select": {
        "size": {
          "signal": "size",
          "mult": 5
        }
      },
      "release": {
        "size": {"signal": "size"}
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "marks"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "text": {
            "field": "datum.supergroup_full_name"
          },
          "fontSize": {"value": 8}
        }
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "label",
          "avoidMarks": ["marks2"],
          "anchor": [
            "top",
            "bottom",
            "right",
            "left"
          ],
          "offset": [1],
          "size": {
            "signal": "[width + 60, height]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "legends": [
    {
      "stroke": "color",
      "symbolType": "circle",
      "title": "ou2_full_name"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share a .pbix with sample data? In the meantime, there is an animated bubble chart here you can refer to which uses a timer instead of play axis: https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase#sp-beeswarm-chart-animated